# EMR Spark cluster mode Hive issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, emr

have an issue with running scala spark 2.1 application in cluster mode.

```
 Release label:emr-5.7.0* 
 Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.7.3
 Applications:Hive 2.1.1, Presto 0.170, Spark 2.1.1, Ganglia 3.7.2, Zeppelin 
 0.7.2, ZooKeeper 3.4.10
```

Have a `.jar` which perfectly working and submitting via `client` mode on the cluster. 
When i try to submit jar in `cluster` mode, i receive an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
```

`...`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:97)
```

Here is how i try to run the application:

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-executors 64 \
--executor-cores 6 \
--driver-memory 6g \
--executor-memory 10g \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/*.jar" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/*.jar" \
--conf "spark.yarn.queue=test_queue" \
--conf "spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=/usr/hive/lib/*.jar" \
--jars /usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
--class MainApp /home/hadoop/app/application-1.0.jar
```

Here is my initialization of `SparkSession`:

```
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName(applicationName)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Could someone give some suggestion, what is worth to try?

PS: `pyspark` application on this cluster works like a charm in cluster mode

Comment: Did **Hive** jars present in all slaves in your cluster?

Comment: @mrsrinivas Yes, all jars are present on slave nodes

Answer (score 0):

```
spark-submit --master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-executors 64 \
--executor-cores 6 \
--driver-memory 6g \
--executor-memory 10g \
--conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/*.jar" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/lib/spark/jars/*.jar" \
--conf "spark.yarn.queue=test_queue" \
--conf "spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=/usr/hive/lib/*.jar" \
--jars /usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-
3.2.9.jar,/usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-
3.2.6.jar,/usr/lib/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
--class MainApp /home/hadoop/app/application-1.0.jar
```

Don't specify where to look for the hive jars with sqpar.sql.hive.metastore.jar. EMR will do that for you itself. Give that a shot.

If it doesn't work, please post your EMR cluster settings.

Comment: Unf. it doesn't help, I have updated question with emr conf

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed, spark looks at obsolete libs